# Connect to Ubuntu remote desktop from CentOS

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, vnc, centos

I have started up a vncserver on my home computer, running Ubuntu 10.10.

I enabled the ability for users to connect, and made it require a password

yesterday I tested this from Ubuntu by typing

```
vncviewer localhost:1
```

and I was able to see my desktop.

Now I am at work using CentOS and I type: `vncviewer x.x.x.x:1` and I am unable to connect.

What should I do to allow for remote desktop over the internet to my home computer? I'd also settle for just being able to get to a terminal on my home computer if the full desktop is not recommended. Thanks!

edits:

CentOS machine is over the internet. Networking setup at home is the computer is connected directly to DSL modem.

Comment: x.x.x.x isn't a valid IP address ;)  But seriously - you haven't given us enough information.  Where is the CentOS machine in relation to the Ubuntu one?  What is your networking setup?  Please give us more clues to help you with.

Comment: Edited post: basically the ubuntu install is right out of the box, and i followed these instructions: http://www.ehow.com/how_5089245_install-vnc-server-ubuntu.html

Comment: @Matt: But it is a valid DNS name.

Comment: @grawity :P~~~~

Answer (score 0):

To make incoming connections, you usually have to set up port forwarding in your home network's router. For VNC, it's TCP ports 5900+*n*, where *n* is the display number. For `:1`, it would be 5901.

---

*However,* since VNC lacks *any* security measures (beyond an optional password which is sent in plain text), it would be more secure to tunnel the connection over SSH.

Install `openssh-server` on Ubuntu, forward the SSH port tcp/22 instead of VNC, and connect from CentOS with:

```
ssh -fNL 5911:localhost:5901 ubuntubox.domain.tld
vncviewer localhost:11
```

Comment: Before you ask: The "DSL modem" _is_ in fact a router (with DSL support).

Comment: I will keep this in mind for later. RIght now the ubuntu box is connected directly to DSL modem

Comment: Ninja edited! haha

Answer (score 0):

This probably won't work.  Unless you have a static IP address, you will not be able to connect to a home network using normal means.  You could use a service like FreeDNS or DynDNS.  There is a nice [tutorial](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1020886) about how set up a system like this.  I don't think you need to actually buy a domain though, I think you can camp on someone else's.  Anyway, here's what happens:

- Your IP address can change frequently
- Your computer will talk to FreeDNS and tell it when it's IP changes
- FreeDNS will route all traffic to your computer

When you get this set up, you will need use a command like this:

`vncviewer yourdomain:port` where yourdomain is the domain registered through FreeDNS or DynDNS and port is the port your vnc server is running on.

It's not too complicated... I set this up in an afternoon and I can access my desktop from anywhere.